# What's wrong with these file permissions?

Tags: permissions

This is an embarassing question, but I can't seem to figure out the proper file permissions for my server. I want to create a directory in my public_html folder that includes read/write access for everyone so that I can easily create files there via php scripts executed when a user loads a web page.

Here's the current permissions showing:

```
drw-rw-rw- 2 root www-data    4096 Aug 27 19:38 TEMPFILES
```

When I execute a php script as a random user who is not root and not in the www-data group, I get an error "Permission denied" when trying to write a file to TEMPFILES. Why is that?

Comment: Use groups, do not allow access to all.

Answer (score 9):

```
chmod a+x TEMPFILES
```

As directories must have the eXecute bit because reasons[1]. (You may also want the sticky bit like is set on for example `/tmp`.)

[1] "Note that read permission for a directory and execute permission for a directory mean different things. Read permission lets us read the directory, obtaining a list of all the filenames in the directory. Execute permission lets us pass through the directory when it is a component of a pathname that we are trying to access." -- Stevens, "APUE" (first edition), chapter 4, section 5.

Comment: can you explain this in more detail? I will only be saving textfiles in that directory, so why do I need execute permissions? If the whole world has both write and execute permissions, this seems crazy. That's why I wanted only write and not execute permissions. What am I missing?

Comment: There *must* be execute permissions on *all* the directories `/in/path/to/TEMPFILES/somefile` as otherwise the program will not have permission to traverse through to `somefile`; the execute bit on a directory controls whether or not a path traversal is allowed. Another option would be to restrict the directory permissions to only that of the webserver, or a group containing the necessary users, if the `o+rwx` bits are problematic.

Comment: @thrig, you should elaborate on the `s` bit.

Comment: `chmod a+X TEMPFILES`  is safer it will only add execute bits where needed (only for directories and files that already have it, for user).

Comment: Directory permissions are about the directory not the files in it. `r` read: allow reading of file-name from within the directory, `x` execute : allow access to files in directory, `w` write: allow adding and removing of files in directory.

Answer (score 0):

Need the execute bit set for the directory

chmod 0777 TEMP FILES

The you can see the conents

Comment: if I do the nuclear option of 777 how do I protect my server at all from folks uploading all sorts of nasty executables?

Comment: Perhaps the poster should read the manual page

Comment: P's it is the permissions for the directory not files uploaded

Comment: The permissions of the directory are not inherited by the files within (unless you use FACL's with default permissions).